# Turning Numpy array values to datetime values with List comprehensions Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list comprehension where it goes through the `ts` array and then turn it into readable timestamps. However the `dates` list comprehension is faulty how would I be able to fix it and get the Expected Output below?

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np 

ts = np.array([1628997394, 1628997444, 1628997602, 1629006977, 1629007021])
# if you encounter a "year is out of range" error the timestamp
# may be in milliseconds, try `ts /= 1000` in that case
dates=[x for x in ts if ts > 0 datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]
```

Error:

```
    dates=[x for x in ts if ts > 0 datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected Output:

```
[2021-08-15 03:16:34 , 2021-08-15 03:17:24, 2021-08-15 03:20:02 , 2021-08-15 05:56:17 , 2021-08-15 05:57:01]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done more efficiently with `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = np.array([1628997394, 1628997444, 1628997602, 1629006977, 1629007021])
>>> pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='s', errors='coerce').dropna().astype(str).to_numpy()
array(['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24',
       '2021-08-15 03:20:02', '2021-08-15 05:56:17',
       '2021-08-15 05:57:01'], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You iterate on `ts` as `x` for checking in `if` you should check `x` NOT check `ts` and end of `for` and `if` when checking condition you need write `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` in the first of list that you want create.

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np 

ts = np.array([1628997394, 1628997444, 1628997602, 1629006977, 1629007021])

dates=[datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in ts if x>0]
```

Output:

```
['2021-08-15 03:16:34',
 '2021-08-15 03:17:24',
 '2021-08-15 03:20:02',
 '2021-08-15 05:56:17',
 '2021-08-15 05:57:01']
```

For checking runtime two solution you can use `%timeit` and see when you can do your job with `list` don't use `numpy` or `pandas` because use an additional library is not good. *(using `list` 10 times faster than using `pandas` for this **short array**)*

Runtime:

```
ts = np.array([1628997394, 1628997444, 1628997602, 1629006977, 1629007021])

%timeit dates=[datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in ts if x>0]
# 27.1 µs ± 899 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='s', errors='coerce').dropna().astype(str).to_numpy()
# 708 µs ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @georgehere I add runtime checking two existing answers and you can see use `list` is 10 time faster than using `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd

ts = np.array([1628997394, 1628997444, 1628997602, 1629006977, 1629007021])

ts1 = pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='s', errors= 'coerce')
```

ts1

solution:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24',
               '2021-08-15 03:20:02', '2021-08-15 05:56:17',
               '2021-08-15 05:57:01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```